# Using Keyboard input for 2 objects

Tags: javascript

edit: SOLVED

I'm a highschool student in Japan trying to learn how to program.
I recently viewed https://vimeo.com/105955605 this video, and decided I could use the beginning section to start building pong in javascript.

I'm pretty much a complete novice with programming and/or javascript and I still have a long way to go.

I got Player1 (left paddle) to work on its own, so I figured I could just copy paste, mess with a couple things, and make Player2. However, now Player2 moves when I press w/s, but Player1 no longer moves.

I've tried creating 2 separate keyboarder() functions, using this.keyboarder from Player1 in player2 (Player2.keyboarder = Player1.keyboarder() ), and declaring/calling keyboarder() before doing anything else.

HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Pong</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <canvas id="screen" width="310" height="210"></canvas>
         <script src="js/pong.js"></script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
    ;(function(){

//Main game function
    //tells objects in bodies array to update.
    //stores gameSize pulled from canvasId
    var Game = function(canvasId){
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        var screen = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var gameSize = {x: canvas.width, y: canvas.height};
        var self = this;
//bodies array
        this.bodies = [new Player1(this, gameSize), new Player2(this, gameSize)];
//update function
        var tick = function(){
        self.update();
        self.draw(screen,gameSize);
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        };
        tick();
    };
//constructer for game() function. tells bodies to update, and draw
    Game.prototype = {
        update: function(){
            for(var i =0 ; i < this.bodies.length; i++){
                this.bodies[i].update();
            }
        },
        draw:function(screen,gameSize){
            screen.clearRect(0,0,gameSize.x,gameSize.y);
            for(var i =0 ; i < this.bodies.length; i++){
                drawRect(screen, this.bodies[i]);
            }
        }
    };
//P1 object, declares size and start position of P1
    var Player1= function(game, gameSize){
        this.size = {x:30,y:gameSize.y / 3};
        this.game = game;
        this.gameSize = gameSize;
        this.center = {x: 0, y:gameSize.y/2};
        this.keyboarder = new Keyboarder();
       requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
    };
//constructor for P1, updates position based on keyboard input
    Player1.prototype = {
        update:function(){
            if (this.keyboarder.isDown(this.keyboarder.KEYS.DOWN) && this.center.y < (5*this.gameSize.y / 6)){
               this.center.y += 4;
            }else if(this.keyboarder.isDown(this.keyboarder.KEYS.UP) && this.center.y > this.size.y /2 ){
                this.center.y -= 4;
            }
        }
    };
//P2, same as P1 aside from position
    var Player2= function(game, gameSize){
        this.size = {x:30,y:gameSize.y / 3};
        this.game = game;
        this.gameSize = gameSize;
        this.center = {x: gameSize.x, y:gameSize.y/2};
        this.keyboarder = new Keyboarder();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.update);
    };
//constructor for P2, same as P1
    Player2.prototype = {
        update:function(){
            if (this.keyboarder.isDown(this.keyboarder.KEYS.S) && this.center.y < (5*this.gameSize.y / 6)){
                this.center.y += 4;
            }else if(this.keyboarder.isDown(this.keyboarder.KEYS.W) && this.center.y > this.size.y /2 ){
                this.center.y -= 4;
            }
        }
    };
//Draw function, draws object
    var drawRect = function(screen, body){
        screen.fillRect(body.center.x - body.size.x /2,
                body.center.y - body.size.y /2, body.size.x,body.size.y);
    };
//Keyboard input function
    //reads if keys are being pressed and takes the event code
    //isDown() returns boolean of key down = true, key up = false
    var Keyboarder = function(
        ){
        var keyState = {};

        window.onkeydown = function(e){
            keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
        };
        window.onkeyup = function(e){
            keyState[e.keyCode] = false;
        };
        this.KEYS = {DOWN: 37, UP:39,W:87 , S: 83};

        this.isDown = function(keyCode){
            return keyState[keyCode] === true;
        };

    };
//calls game() function when the page has loaded.
    window.onload = function(){
        new Game("screen")
    };
})();
```

Sorry if this is bad protocol for using stackoverflow, I'm also new to asking questions here.

Comment: No need to edit it to say it's been solved - if one of the answers has helped you fix your problem, you can accept it using the tick.  If more than one was useful, feel free to vote up both of them and pick one to choose as the "most helpful".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create two `Keyboarder` instances, one collides with the other, because of this:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
};
window.onkeyup = function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode] = false;
};
```

When you create one `Keyboarder`, the event listeners the previous one attached are overriden. Try something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

This ensures there are listeners for every instance of the `Keyboarder`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two `Keyboarder` instances, and they're both binding to the key events by assigning a handler directly to them - this will overwrite any other handlers.  There's two ways to fix it:

1: Don't assign directly, instead use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), eg:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
});
```

2: Use the same `keyboarder` instance for both players:

```
var kb = new Keyboarder();
this.bodies = [new Player1(this, gameSize, kb), new Player2(this, gameSize, kb)];
```

and in your player object assign it to this 3rd parameter.  Even if you go this route, I would still advise on using `addEventListener` as well simply to ensure that the events can be bound to in multiple places if needed.

On another point, you should also be able to refactor your players into a single function and create two instances of it with different parameters, but that sort of thing is better dealt with over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).